# upload audio on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, audio, blobstore

I am creating an html page on google app engine in which a user can record his voice and upload to server. I am implementing it in google app engine and have recorded audio and generate the url which have blob:http://xxx.xx format. Now I want to upload it to blobstore of google app engine.

How can I upload this generated audio file.

Comment: Q very unclear. What language on the App Engine side? Where is now your recorded audio and how did you "generate" that `blob:...` URL?  Are you asking how to upload from your browser to that URL, or do you already have the data in App Engine and want to ensure it goes into cloud storage (blobstore's *NOT* recommended for use in new apps!)...?

Comment: Language on app engine is python. and the audio right now in browser media storage whose address is in blob. I need to know how to call the python class to upload it to gae.

Comment: @AlexMartelli any reason in particular to recommend NOT using blobstore? I have been following the GCS vs blobsotre debacle for some time now and havent really been convinced GCS is "the better" choice.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Writing_files_to_the_Blobstore is ominous to me and suggests that more generally cloud storage is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice sample code in the official documentation illustrating how to [upload images to the blobstore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/).

With few modifications you can make it work for audio as well. Note that you can only use get_serving_url on BLOB image files.

I would also recommend you to store the audio files on GCS instead of the blobstore (sample code in the same tutorial). You will then be able to serve those audio files directly from GCS instead of having a serve handler in your application.